# How to make a heat map in R based on a gif of the human body?

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap

I have a gif of a human body and need to plot a heat map on it . The data to be used is in R

I have found instructions on how to import a gif but it is the getting my data onto the gif that I am unsure of.

I presume I would need to put the gif on a grid at first and then get some co-ordinates and then assign the data to the relevant co-ordinates ?

For example if the head was located at (5,10), the stomach at (5,5) , the right knee at (4,3) etc etc on a grid .

Is there a package people use for this or is it just a task of programming strictly in R with no packages ? or do you use another resource ?

Answer (score 8):

If you find an SVG image that you can use, you can also use the `grImport` package to transform the file in an XML, which then makes it easy to modify with R.

For example, if you want to use [this file](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Human_body_front_and_side.svg), you can add some `fill` shapes to the image using Illustrator/Gimp or anything else and [then transform it to an XML using `grImport`](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v30/i04/paper):

```
library(grImport)
PostScriptTrace("yourimage.ps")
```

This will create an `yourimage.ps.xml` file. If you want you can modify the `ids` of the fill path nodes in the XML to access them more easily to change the colors.

For example here, I made 14 body parts on the SVG file and changed their ids to names instead of number, you can find the XML here:
[Human SVG with bodyparts XML](https://gist.github.com/erardnicolas/da67b1692027c84fbe6c)

To change the colors of the bodyparts, you can just change the `rgb` part of the `fill` nodes:

```
library(grImport)
library(XML)
library(gridExtra)

#function to change the rgb color of the xml paths
changeColor<-function(bodypart,color){
        node<-xpathSApply(doc, paste("//path[@id='",bodypart,"']/context/rgb",sep=""))[[1]]
        rgbCol<-col2rgb(color)
        xmlAttrs(node)["r"]=rgbCol[1]/255
        xmlAttrs(node)["g"]=rgbCol[2]/255
        xmlAttrs(node)["b"]=rgbCol[3]/255
}

#read the xml image
doc<-xmlParse("Human_body_front_and_side.ps.xml")

#these are the different parts you can change
bodyparts<-c("head","hand-right","hand-left","foot-left","foot-right","lowerleg-left","lowerleg-right",
            "upperleg-left","upperleg-right","torso","forearm-right","forearm-left","upperarm-right","upperarm-left")

#color the bodyparts with random color
mapply(function(x,y){changeColor(x,y)},bodyparts,sample(colours(), 14))


#load the XML as a picture
body<-readPicture(saveXML(doc))

#plot it
grid.arrange(pictureGrob(body), ncol=1)
```

I get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You may find the [grid](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid-package.html) package useful.