# Color visualization for different parts of a diagram

Tags: r

I have some gene expression data in different parts of plant roots (see the image) and I want to show the gene expression levels in different parts of the roots. For example, if the gene is highly expressed in the apical meristem, I want to mark the apical meristem part of the schematic diagram red. One possibility is to make the diagram a map, does anyone have any suggestion how to make a diagram to a map in R? Or if you know any tool for this purpose, please let me know. Thank you!

[The plant root structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv7AD.jpg)

Comment: SO only accepts raster image files, but if your original has actual structure you could color individual polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw your own polygons to separate the regions using [the `raster` package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/draw). Or, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664798/how-to-make-a-heat-map-in-r-based-on-a-gif-of-the-human-body?lq=1) may provide a better way to do this.

Then, you can create a heat map and color within the polygons. Say, with `ggplot2::geom_polygon()`

To make it look even better, you could use the original image as a background, and then overlay your heat map with some transparency (i.e. the `alpha` argument in `ggplot2`) so you can see the colored heat map and some of the original image. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409935/plot-data-over-background-image-with-ggplot) for more details, or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848145/heat-map-with-image-as-background?lq=1) if you like funny pictures

Comment: Thanks so much, BarkelyBG! The human body post is the one I need since I have a SVG file for cell shape.