# R: interact with customized XML map

Tags: r

A Stack Overflow discussion here ([How to make a heat map in R based on a gif of the human body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664798/how-to-make-a-heat-map-in-r-based-on-a-gif-of-the-human-body?lq=1)) describe how to plot a map for different part of human body in R. 
I want to make the plot more interactive, i.e. if I move the cursor to the torso, I want to see a message "torso". 
In other words, what I want to do is similar to the "identify" function for scattor plot, but is for plots generated from XML. 
Another example for what I would like to achieve is: https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/
Thanks!